# guardar datos python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy haciendo un programa en python y no se la forma de almacenar los datos (listas) cargados en algun sitio para que al momento de volver a iniciar el programa se vuelvan a cargar y no se pierdan. los datos se tienen que leer y poder seguir siendo manipulados... borrar, cargar mas, etc si alguien sabe la respuesta seria de muy gran ayuda

Comment: Una base de datos tal vez amigo

Comment: se tiene que guardar en la pc del usuario ya que es información sensible y offline. si sabes o conoces algún vídeo que lo explique seria muy bienvenido desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Podrías guardarlo por ejemplo en un archivo serializado con pickle?
Si eso te vale, puedes guardarlo así:

```
import pickle

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

with open('archivoSerializado', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(lista, f)
```

Verás que con eso te aparece un archivo nuevo (archivoSerializado) en la misma ruta que tu script, y para acceder a los datos desde python puedes cargarlo así:

```
with open('archivoSerializado', 'rb') as f:
    listaRecuperada = pickle.load(f)

print(listaRecuperada)  #>> Devolvería la lista [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] guardada en 'listaRecuperada'
```

Comment: la lista y el import se pondría fuera del while True y los with adentro? o todo afuera?

Comment: Qué while True? en mi código no hay ninguno...

Comment: en mi programa tengo un while ```                                                  total=[]
while True:
    op=str(input("""
elige una opcion
1: agregar o borrar clientes
2: buscar clientes
3: mostrar todos los clientes
4: salir del programa
opcion: """))
    op.lower() ``` no lo puedo poner como frgmento de codogo pero mas o menos se ve

Comment: El import ponlo arriba del todo, al comienzo del código.  El primer bloque with es para grabar los datos que necesites serializados en el archivo una vez los tengas (en este caso solamente guarda la lista). El segundo with es para recuperar lo que hay en el archivo asi que ponlo en donde quieras emplear lo que hayas guardado.

Comment: Inténtalo asi, y si ves que no lo consigues, crea una nueva pregunta mejor que ponerlo en los comentarios, que así será más fácil darte una respuesta más detallada.

Comment: El problema es al recuperar los datos  ya que cambia el nombre de la lista y si la parte de recuperación la pongo dentro del while la vuelve a vaciar ya que la declara vacía... yo lo que pensaba es en almacenar los datos en un archivo python para luego recuperarlo  con open wride closed

Comment: El nuevo nombre es el que yo le he puesto a la variable, puedes poner el que quieras, ten en cuenta que los datos los tienes guardados en el archivo, el nombre de la variable da igual. Lo que entiendo que deberias hacer es primero leer el archivo (con lo segundo que te he puesto) y luego hacer lo que vayas a hacer con los datos, y por ultimo guardarlo en el archivo con los cambios que sea.